# which values van the various AC_CANONICAL_* variables have?

Tags: operating-system, autoconf

in our autotools project, we are using [`AC_CANONICAL_HOST`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.71/html_node/Canonicalizing.html) to determine the host architecture/OS/... via the `host` (resp `host_cpu`, `host_os` and `host_vendor`) variable(s).

Traditionally this involves (at least for us) to `configure` on real installations of the actual host, see what values we get and adjust our logic to do the right thing™.

Now it's obviously a bit awkward for having to check these values on real (or virtualized) systems.

Is there some list of canonical output of the `AC_CANONICAL_*` macros?